# How to do a simple 1-line pattern match? (Getting a Bool out of a pattern match)

Tags: haskell

In the following code, how do I check -- only by adding a one-liner beside the `if` -- whether `foo` is `Yes`?

```
data Asdf = Yes | No | Other

foo :: Asdf
foo = Yes

hello :: String
hello =
    if <check if foo is Yes> -- How?
     then "foo is Yes"
     else "foo isn't Yes"
```

I know I can use `case`, but the point of this question is to somehow get a `Bool` out of it. This will be useful for me in unit tests, etc. (`case` can quickly get a quite messy.)

Comment: You should let `Asdf` deriving from `Eq`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
hello =
    if (case foo of {Yes -> True; _ -> False})
     then "foo is Yes"
     else "foo isn't Yes"
```

But this definitely isn't something I would recommend. If you can use an `Eq` instance like suggested by Willem Van Onsem and bheklir then fair enough; but generally I'd avoid Eq too. I don't think you should strive to get a bool – booleans are always the least informative way to deal with some information. Using a `case` directly

```
hello =
    case foo of
     Yes -> "foo is Yes"
     _ -> "foo isn't Yes"
```

*is better*; if this is too clunky in a collection of unit test then why not define a suitable helper function that does basically the same thing?

Comment: I'm definitely after a 1-liner for unit tests. Something I can use right beside `assertBool`. That's why I'm liking your first solution. For instance `assertBool (case foo of {Yes -> True; _ -> False})`. It's not great, but I don't see how writing tons of helper functions that all look like `SomethingIsValue` improves things. What do you think?

Comment: (I also agree with you that deriving `Eq` isn't all that great, because `Eq` means something more than that. Plus, that wouldn't work if the value constructors took arguments - arguments that I don't care about in unit tests.)

Comment: @haskellHQ I would find the `assertBool` you mention to be alright. If you frequently use that, perhaps a function `isYes` doing the same check would be more convenient.

Comment: Yes, I'd write `assertYes :: Asdf -> Assertion`; `assertYes Yes = return ()`; `assert Yes q = assertFailure $ "Expected Yes, got "++show q`.

Comment: For what it’s worth, you can omit the braces: `case foo of Yes -> True; _ -> False`.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be to `derive (Eq)` on your type:

```
data Asdf = Yes | No | Other deriving (Eq)
```

Then you can use use `==` like normal:

```
hello =
    if foo == Yes
        then "foo is Yes"
        else "foo isn't Yes"
```

There are a number of potentially useful typeclasses you can derive additional, like `Ord`, `Enum`, `Show`, and `Read`.